# Proper way to test for NA in Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, julia

What is the proper way to test if a value in a DataFrame is NA in the Julia DataFrames package?

I have this far found out that `typeof(var) == NAtype` works, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `typeof(var) == NAtype` for this is awkward, in particular because it is not vectorized.

The canonical way of testing for `NA` values is to use the (vectorized) function called `isna`.

### Example

Let's generate a toy DataFrame with some `NA` values in the `B` column:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = 2:2:20)
10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | 2  |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | 8  |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
| 6   | 6  | 12 |
| 7   | 7  | 14 |
| 8   | 8  | 16 |
| 9   | 9  | 18 |
| 10  | 10 | 20 |

julia> df[[1,4,8],symbol("B")] = NA
NA

julia> df
10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | NA |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | NA |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
| 6   | 6  | 12 |
| 7   | 7  | 14 |
| 8   | 8  | NA |
| 9   | 9  | 18 |
| 10  | 10 | 20 |
```

Now let's pretend we don't know the contents of our DataFrame and ask, for example, the following question:

> Does column `B` contain an `NA` values?

The `typeof` approach won't work, here:

```
julia> typeof(df[:,symbol("B")]) == NAtype
false
```

The `isna` function is more adequate:

```
julia> any(isna(df[:,symbol("B")]))
  true
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jub0bs answer, If one would like to check whether a DataFrame contains any `NaN` values or not, the following code can help:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = 2:2:20)
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     2      4
   3 │     3      6
   4 │     4      8
   5 │     5     10
   6 │     6     12
   7 │     7     14
   8 │     8     16
   9 │     9     18
  10 │    10     20


julia> any(isnan.(Matrix(df)))
false
```

This means there aren't any `NaN` values in the given DataFrame!